# Angular routes for OTF components

Tags: angular, dynamic, routes, components

We're using angular 6, creating components on the fly and defining routes for them using the code below:

```
const template = '<span>generated on the fly: {{name}}</span>';
const tmpCmp = Component({ template: template })(class {
  });
const tmpModule = NgModule({ declarations: [tmpCmp] })(class {
  });

await this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
  .then((factories) => {
    const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
    const cmpRef = this.vc.createComponent(tmpCmp);
    cmpRef.instance.name = 'dynamic';

    appRoutes.push({ path: 'dynamic', component: tmpCmp});

  })

this.router.resetConfig(appRoutes);
```

When we navigate to the dynamically created component's url, we get an error:

> No component factory found for ConfirmComponent. Did you add it to
>   @NgModule.entryComponents?

**What are we missing, is this scenario supported ?**

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52408757/2545680). I'll write an article soon that explains why my solution works and why yours doesn't work. [Follow me on Twitter](https://twitter.com/maxim_koretskyi) to get notified

Comment: Thank you, your example works for my case. Sorry for late reply, will follow you up on that article :)

Comment: cool, good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const template = '<span>generated on the fly: {{name}}</span>';
    const tmpCmp = Component({template: template})(class {
    });

    const routes = [{path: '', component: tmpCmp}];
    const tmpModule = NgModule({imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)], declarations: [tmpCmp]})(class {
    });

    this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(tmpModule).then((ngModuleFactory) => {

      const appRoutes = [...this.router.config];

      const route = {
        path: 'dynamic',
        loadChildren() {
          return ngModuleFactory;
        }
      };

      appRoutes.push(route);

      this.router.resetConfig(appRoutes);

      // test navigation
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/dynamic');
    });
  }
```